# meaning integer 26 in SNMP

Tags: linux, snmp, switching, snmpd

I'm starting with SNMP with SNMPwalk ... And I always find that next to the OIDs ' Integer = 26 ' appears.

What does it mean?

Example Code:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.200.203.184.30.98.3 = INTEGER: 26
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.200.203.184.32.34.183 = INTEGER: 26
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.200.211.255.17.129.22 = INTEGER: 26
```

OR

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.3.11.20.167.139.159.35.83 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.3.11.20.167.139.159.35.160 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.3.11.36.94.190.4.46.254 = INTEGER: 3
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: In your example, INTEGER is the type of data returned by an SNMP GET operation for the specified OID .  The actual data returned is the number following "INTEGER: "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2` points to a column `dot1dTpFdbPort` in `dot1dTpFdbTable`.

You need a MIB browser so as to visually analyze the table with more details.

The postfix like `.200.203.184.30.98.3` is the actual index `dot1dTpFdbAddress` (which is a MAC address).

The value of 26 refers to port 26 of this device, if you read [the description of `dot1dTpFdbPort`](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmppro-mib/blob/master/BRIDGE-MIB.txt#L831)

The other group of objects are similar.

You cannot learn SNMP without reading the MIB documents.